# Why don't this example work out for the derivative form of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

### #1: What I know

Hello,

the fundamental theorem of calculus (ftoc) $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$ can be checked by an simple example.

- $f(x) = x$, $F(x) = 0.5x^2$
- $a=0$, $b=1$

The left hand side (lhs) will be $\int_0^1 x dx = 0.5x^2 \Bigr |_0^1 = 0.5(1)^2 - 0.5(0)^2 = 0.5 \kern{5mm} (I)$
and right hand side (rhs) will be $0.5(1)^2 - 0.5(0)^2 = 0.5 \kern{5mm} (II)$

Thus the equation is satisfied.

### #2: What I tried to gain further knowledge

Now rewriting the ftoc gives $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b - a} = \frac{dF(x)}{dx} \Bigr |_a^b = f(x) \Bigr|_a^b = f(b) - f(a) \kern{5mm} (III)$

Using the example from above gives for the lhs $\frac{F(1) - F(0)}{1-0} = \frac{0.5(1)^2 - 0.5(0)^2}{1-0} = 0.5 \kern{5mm} (IV)$ and the rhs gives $f(1) - f(0) = 1 \kern{5mm} (V)$. So the equation is not satisfied.

Where is my error?

### #3: Further, trying to connect these ideas in a visual context

I currently study this to get a better visual understanding of this theorem. $(I)$ says that the area below linear graph of $x$ in the interval $I \in [a, b]$ is equal to the value of the parabola at value of $F(b)$ minus the value at $F(a)$. To understand this backwards it tried to rewrite the ftoc in a derivative form like $(III)$. I thought I could say that the slope of the parabola from $(IV)$ on the interval $I$, the value of $F(b)$ minus $F(a)$ divided by the interval $I$, would be equal to the value of the linear function $f(x)=x$ at $f(b)$ minus $f(a)$. Unluckily there is a reasoning error somewhere.

I suspect it in $(III)$, but can't pin it down.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{dx}$?

Comment: I have corrected it. It should be $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}$.

Comment: The derivative is an local/"instant" rate of change of the function, while $\frac{F(b) - F(a)}{b - a}$ it's an average/global rate of change.

Comment: $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b - a} = \frac{dF(x)}{dx} \Bigr |_a^b$ is not right. And I don't wish to be unkind, but I've tried to figure out some valid equation that is similar to it, and I can't find one. @PauloEstêvão 's comment is perhaps the best observation: the FTOC does not relate to average rates of change.

Comment: But isn't this valid for $lim_{h \to 0} a+h=b$?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by that, but I will note that things that have equal limits can be unequal at every point before taking the limit.

Comment: But if you are asking about $\lim_{b \rightarrow a} \frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}$, that's equal to $F'(a)$, not what you have written.

Comment: So to come back to $(III)$, is this true if the difference between $a$ & $b$ is infinitesimally small?

Comment: No, not even then. And it goes wrong at the very first "equality". Speaking _incredibly_ loosely, you're starting with examining a difference. And a derivative measures a difference, at an infinitesimal level. But when you write $\frac{dF(x)}{dx} \Bigr |_a^b$, you're compute a difference of a difference - it's one difference too many!

Comment: All right. I get your point, but is it possible to formulate the theorem in a form with a derivative?

Comment: Well, $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t) dt = f(x)$ contains a derivative, and I consider it to be like the first half of the FTOC. But that's the closest I can get.